# Phonegap:Get the file from sdcard and upload it to the FTP Server in android

Tags: android, cordova, ftp, phonegap-plugins

I am very new with phonegap developement.In my app there is one button and on clicking on that button the directory structure of **sdcard** will open and by selecting an file that selected file will uploaded to the **FTP Server**.

I tried this link [ftpclient](https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient)  but it doesn't specify how to open the directory structure and select the file and it wont work at all.

Can any one give me proper steps or solution of above.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which type of file do you want to upload?

Comment: any file .txt,.pdf,etc..Thnks.

Comment: Do you have the idea to implement the plugins?

Comment: No first time i am developing this phonegap app.I just follow all the steps that the link will provided..but it not works..:(

Comment: Okk i am giving you the link of a plugin implement it. and you can ask if you have any difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the plugin for `FileChooser` which will give you the option to choose the file from SDCard. [cordova-filechooser](https://github.com/don/cordova-filechooser). and please change the `filechooser.js` file like this

```
(function( cordova ) {

function FileChooser() {}

    FileChooser.prototype.open = function(win, fail) {
        return cordova.exec(
            function (args) { if(win !== undefined) { win(args); } },
            function (args) { if(fail !== undefined) { fail(args); } },
            "FileChooser", "open", []);
    };

    if(!window.plugins) {
        window.plugins = {};
    }

    if (!window.plugins.FileChooser) {
        window.plugins.FileChooser = new FileChooser();
    }

})( window.cordova );
```

Add this `js` file in your `js` folder. And use like this

```
plugins.FileChooser.open(function (uri) {
                // success
            alert(uri); 

            },function () {
               // fail
                alert('failed');
            });
```

Comment: Add the plugin in your `config.xml` file. If you have any doubts. You can ask here.

Comment: sorry to say that it wont works.I just add the above code in filechooser.js and in my index.js file on button click i add this secound one..also i import the filechooser.js in index.html..plugins also added like that.. <plugin name="FileChooser" value="com.example.eos.FileChooser"/>

Comment: In config.xml add `<feature name="FileChooser">
       <param name="android-package" value="com.example.eos.FileChooser" />
 </feature>`

Comment: And on button click call the last piece of code i have provided. which is `plugins.FileChooser.open`

Comment: No dude it won't works..I just add this plugins and also add the plugins.Fliechoser.open on button click but not perform any action.

Comment: And yes please call the above in `deviceready` method. And see if you have added the `cordova.js` file in your index.html.

Comment: which part i want to add in device ready method and where can you please tell me???

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#Login_button', function () {
   
    
   // alert(1);
    
    plugins.FileChooser.open(function (uri) {
        // success
    alert(uri); 

    },function () {
       // fail
        alert('failed');
    }); 
    
 });

Comment: Have you added the cordova.js? put you lines in onDeviceReady method.

Comment: Yes i have added the cordova.js..and if you give alert on button click then alert display i think the problem is other.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50099/discussion-between-nil-and-user3110424)